# Error message after upgrading pip

Tags: linux, python, pip

When using pip, I kept getting a message about me using an old version and I could upgrade, so I did:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

while in my account on a computing cluster.

Now when I even try:

```
pip --version
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/opt/tools/python/2.7.13/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

When I look in:

```
.local/bin/
```

I see:

```
pip
pip2
pip2.7
```

I was advised to try to change pip to pip.old, but this didn't seem to have any effect.

I can't change anything in:

```
/opt/tools/python/2.7.13/bin/
```

I would like to fix this or just revert back to the version I was previously using.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and [install `pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). Install whatever Python you want (e.g., `pyenv install 3.6.5`), use `pyenv global 3.6.5` to set the version globally, then never use the system Python again.

---

I [had the same issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2122) under Ubuntu which was due to not having the correct `PATH` set up.

Under Ubuntu, this is what I did first in order to reset the system `pip`:

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python-pip --reinstall
```

And optionally for Python 3:

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
```

Then, make sure that your shell profile contains the following:

```
export PATH="${HOME}/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Reload the shell. Now when you call `pip`, it should call the correct version of pip for Python 2.

If want to upgrade the system `pip`, I am not going to give you any advice, as it's not even recommended from what I've seen (and also judging from the various problems that may result from that). Python's ecosystem is [kind of broken](https://xkcd.com/1987/) there.